# Kanonische Reihenfolge der Kasus

Tags: grammatical-case, terminology, nomenclature

Die morphologisch sinnvolle Reihenfolge der Kasus im Deutschen ist **Nominativ, Akkusativ, Dativ, Genitiv** (NADG). So wird meines Wissens auch in den meisten Fachtexten und im DaF-Unterricht sowie seit 2005 in der Duden-Grammatik (von Peter Eisenberg etc.) verfahren. 
Die traditionelle Schulgrammatik reiht hingegen **Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ, Akkusativ** (NGDA), bezeichnet sie ggf. mit den entsprechenden Fragepronomen als *wer?-, wes(sen)?-, wem?-* und *wen?*-Fall und nummeriert sie auch noch entsprechend (1. bis 4. Fall). 
Das ist auch die klassische Reihenfolge der [lateinischen Grammatik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinische_Grammatik#Deklinationen_.28Klassen.2FSt.C3.A4mme.29), wo noch der Ablativ und evtl. der Vokativ folgen, obwohl die Ähnlichkeit der Flexionssuffixe auch dort eher für Nom, Vok, Akk, Abl, Dat, Gen (oder sogar Akk vor Nom!) spräche. 
Auch die Altgriechische Grammatik, von der ich absolut keine Ahnung habe, scheint üblicherweise die unlogische NGDA(V)-Reihenfolge zu verwenden, obwohl dort ebenfalls der Vokativ dem Nominativ gleicht und auf den ersten Blick nichts gegen N(V)ADG spräche.

Ist der einzige Grund für die schulgrammatische Reihenfolge der Fälle also Tradition und diese auch noch eher zufällig gewählt?

### Begründung NADG

Der Nominativ bildet immer die morphologisch am wenigsten komplexe Form und ist als Subjektkasus in fast jedem Satz vertreten. Daher ist er die Nennform und steht sinnvollerweise am Anfang (oder evtl. am Ende).

Den Akkusativ gibt es bei Substantiven, Adjektiven und Artikelwörtern nur im Maskulinum (also auch nicht im Plural) sowie bei Pronomen der 1. und 2. Person. Ansonsten entspricht er formal immer dem Nominativ, sollte also neben diesem stehen.

Feminine Begleiter unterscheiden nie zwischen Dativ und Genitiv, die anderen Klassen manchmal nicht (schwache/gemischte Flexion), dafür weisen alle Substantive, wenn möglich, im GenSg und im DatPl abweichende Formen auf. Im Singular gleichen sich also eher Nom/Akk und Dat, im Plural eher Nom/Akk und Gen. Nur die Personalpronomen sprechen klar dafür, Dativ direkt auf Akkusativ folgen zu lassen. Außerdem sind diese beiden die üblichen Objektfälle, während der Genitiv heute weitgehend auf (oft possessive) Attribute beschränkt ist.

Comment: Verwandte Frage (englisch): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7861/numbering-cases

Comment: @chirlu Danke, nächstes Mal denke ich vorm Fragen hoffentlich daran, auch auf Englisch zu suchen.

Comment: Die Reihenfolge ist schon bei der ersten (erhaltenen) griechischen Grammatik, der von [Dionysios Thrax](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysios_Thrax), NGDAV. Auch die Namen der Fälle sind dort schon so, wie sie später ins Lateinische lehnübersetzt wurden (aufrechter Fall (_casus rectus_), Abstammungsfall, Gebefall, Anklagefall, Ruffall). Von daher gehe ich stark davon aus, daß Tradition die Erklärung ist. Einen „griechischen“ Grund für die Reihenfolge sehe ich übrigens auch nicht.

Comment: Hm, sind diese Dinge nicht für jede Art von Anwendung oder Erlernen der Sprache ganz unwichtig?

Comment: @MartinPeters Wenn man Nom und Akk in einer Deklinationstabelle direkt untereinander darstellt, sieht man ziemlich schnell, dass sie sich fast nicht unterscheiden. Das bietet offenbar eine Verständnis- und Lernvorteil, der verschiedentlich als Grund für die NADG-Reihenfolge in modernem DaF-Material genannt wird.

Comment: @Crissov Ist ja alles richtig, aber selbst wenn es nicht untereinander geschrieben ist, kann man die Ähnlichkeit bemerken.

Comment: @MartinPeters Man *kann*. Wenn aber Psychologie oder Pädagogik feststellen, dass die moderne Reihenfolge messbar positive Auswirkungen auf das Erlernen der Sprache hat, dann ist sie offenbar nicht „ganz unwichtig“. (Jetzt müsste nur noch jemand eine Referenz zu solch einer Untersuchung bringen.)

Comment: Weil mir der Gedanke gerade gekommen ist: die sind nach "Entfernung" sortiert. Nominativ: Ich, eine handelnde Person => HIER, Genitiv: Im Besitz von jemandem, der hier ist (oder davon abstammend) es gibt ein unmittelbares verhältnis => NAH, Dativ: nah genug für eine direkte interaktion, aber ohne direkte verbindung zum hier => MITTEL, Akkusativ: eine richtung in raum/zeit vorgebend: FERN.  Mir ist klar, dass das unglaublich große Schwächen als Regel hat und gar nicht taugt, aber den Gedanken fand ich gerade ganz nett.