# Overview of nominative, accusative and dative for all pronouns

Tags: dative, pronoun, accusative, nominative

I am "new" in German learning. I found [this table](https://deutschlernerblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Deklination-Deutsch-Artikel-Artikelw%C3%B6rter-Pronomen-Adjektive-A1-A2.png) (bellow). According to the table the accusative of "mein" for the third person singular neutral (es) is: **meines**? However, in this [other link](https://germanwithlaura.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/possessive-pronoun_chart.svg), it says it is **meins**, and I saw other websites that say just **mein**. So I am confused now. Can someone suggest a reliable source where I can see an overview with most of the cases, like in the picture?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, this declension for *mein* depends on whether (or the way) *mein* is tied to a noun:

> Das ist **mein** Haus (*attributiv*)
> Dein Haus ist groß. **Meines** ist klein. (*nicht attributiv*)
> (Dein Haus ist groß.) Das **meine** ist klein. (*nicht attributiv mit Artikel*)

A nice table is for me that of [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein). I would post it, but one cannot write tables here in SE.

Comment: what about "meins", in the second link it is mentioned. Also, do you know a table where also also depicted dein, sein, ein, kein, etc?

Comment: @BurNor *meins* is the same as *meines* in this case. As for the table, you just have to look at the corresponding table in Wiktionary. It has them all.

Answer (score 1):

All three are correct. It depends on the usage.

- as an attribute of a noun (before a noun)

  > Ich sehe **mein** Kind.
- non attributive, without an article.

  > Welches Kind siehst du? - Ich sehe **meines.**
- non attributive, with an article.

  > Welches Kind siehst du? - Ich sehe **das meine.**

Also note, that the order of the cases in the picture is unusual. The standard order is:

1. Fall = Nominativ
2. Fall = Genitiv
3. Fall = Dativ
4. Fall = Akkusativ

The term »Dritter Fall« is a synonyme for »Dativ« etc.

The reliable source is [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein).

Comment: what about "meins", in the second link it is mentioned. Also, do you know a table where also also depicted dein, sein, ein, kein, etc?

Comment: Regarding the order of the cases, see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7861/numbering-cases

Comment: @Hubert what do you think (-e) (-en) (-er) in the in gray in the table (from the figure  attached to the post) meant? I dont understand their significance